# what does a live CD need to boot?

Tags: linux, boot, livecd

Several years ago, I used an Ubuntu live CD with some windows hard drive disk (HDD) and managed to make an Ubuntu OS bootable HDD.
At that time it was easy, as I remember.

Now, I'm trying, for a day now, to do the same with no understanding on whatever is going on...
I picked 2 HDD in good condition (with no bad sector).
The first had a luks ubuntu on it with a forgotten password that I wanted to get rid of, and the second was a corrupted windows.

The first thing I did was just to put the HDD in a computer (tried for both HDD and got the same result), put the ubuntu live CD, and thought it will just take 5 minutes.
But the Ubuntu live CD didn't want to boot.

```
EDD : Error 1000 reading sector 355579. NO Default or UI configuration
directive found !
```

I tried an old live CD of BT3 (Kali) and it ran until the following error:

```
* Looking for data directory
Fatal error occured – BT3 data not found.
You are maybe using an unsupported boot device (eg. SCSI or old PCMCIA).
Workaround : Copy the directory BT3 from your boot device to an IDE/SATA disk, eg. To /mnt/hda1/BT3 or C : \BT3.
Then try to boot again.
* Something went wrong and we can’t continue. This should never happen. 
* Please reboot your computer with Ctrl+Alt+Delete …
```

With Hiren's CD, or Ultimate boot CD, `_` is displayed blinking for ages.

I guess there might be some partitioning to be done, and the bootloader has to be written, but I don't really understand why because for me a live CD should have a bootloader in it, then it should start with an empty HDD...

Could you enlighten me here? 
"try this" and "this that" answers will might be helpful, but I would rather like an detailed answer about what It needs to be done for a live CD to boot. What does a live CD needs in order to work properly? Especially, can a live CD boot with a corrupted HDD or no HDD?

*note:* computer is ASUS X53S with EFI BIOS.

---

i managed to make hiren's boot CD (HBCD), but I don't understand why and really how because it seems to work once every twice.
Sometimes it works so I tried to launch mini XP with HBCD, i get the following error:

```
INF File txtsetup.sif is corrupt or missing, status 4096. Setup cannot continue. Press any key to exit
```

Sometimes it launches grub and I don't get to HBCD menu.

Anyway, I still don't understand what happened with the live CD, but I got myself a live USB stick with distros through YUMI, and, it's a peace of cake.
So, I still want to understand what's happening here, even if I found a workaround.

Comment: Have you tried booting via legacy mode in the EFI Firmware?  You can boot to legacy via entering the EFI Boot Menu or enabling it within the EFI Firmware settings.  This should resolve your issue.

Comment: There is a "launch EFI Shell from file sytem device" but when I enter this option i get a "not found" message. There is also an option "UEFI Boot" in the boot configuration panel of the BIOS, which I can enable, what I did but with no result. There is no more "EFI" tagged option in the BIOS...

Comment: In the EFI firmware, there will be two boot type options, one being EFI, which requires digitally signed bootloaders (usually set to this by default) and the other being Legacy/MBR mode, which disables this functionality, allowing the EFI firmware to boot like a legacy BIOS.  If enabling Legacy/MBR in as a boot option does not work, simply create a new [LiveCD/LiveUSB](https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop)

Comment: nothing happened for the Ubuntu live CD, but the hiren's CD is now booting...Thanks. But why?

Comment: You'll find a better explanation by googling [EFI vs BIOS](https://www.google.com/search?source=hp&ei=-VNZXfTTDYugtQWgmZaIDA&q=EFI+versus+BIOS&oq=EFI+versus+BIOS&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i13l10.734.5726..5892...3.0..0.157.2196.5j14......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i131j0j0i10j0i22i30j0i22i10i30j0i13i10j0i13i10i30j0i13i5i30.5l1cU6mYGXc&ved=0ahUKEwi0tNbMxIzkAhULUK0KHaCMBcEQ4dUDCAc&uact=5)